# When installing materall-ui for react getting error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, material-ui

Getting following error while trying to install material-ui

```
error Darwin 16.7.0

error argv "/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/npm" "install" "material-ui"

34 error node v7.5.0

35 error npm  v4.1.2

36 error code ENOTFOUND

37 error errno ENOTFOUND

38 error syscall getaddrinfo

39 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND npme.xxxxx.com npme.xxxxxx.com:443

40 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

40 error network and is related to network connectivity.

40 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

40 error network

40 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

40 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs, I think that you had a bad internet connection while downloading the material-ui module.

Check your internet connection first before downloading any modules.
The syntax for downloading the material-ui would be

```
npm install --save material-ui
```